# Find matches in two different Powershell objects based on one property

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find the matching names in two different types of Powershell objects

$Object1 has two properties - Name (string), ResourceID (uint32)

$object2 has one noteproperty - Name (system.string)

This gives me a list of the matching names but I also want the corresponding resourceID property from $object1.

```
$computers = Compare-Object $Object1.name $WSD_CM12 | where {$_.sideindicator -eq "=>"} | foreach {$_.inputobject}
```

These are big objects with over 10,000 items so I'm looking for the most efficient way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative method:

```
# Create sample list of objects with both Name and Serial
$obj1 = New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property:@{ Name = "Foo"; Serial = "1234" }
$obj2 = New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property:@{ Name = "Cow"; Serial = "4242" }
$collection1 = @($obj1, $obj2)

# Create subset of items with only Name
$objA = New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property:@{ Name = "Foo"; }
$collection2 = @($objA)

#Everything above this line is just to make sample data
# replace $collection1 and $collection2 with $Object1, $WSD_CM12
# Combine into one list
($collection1 + $collection2) | 
    # Group by name property
    Group-Object -Property Name | 
    # I only want items that exist in both
    Where { $_.Count -gt 1 } | 
    # Now give me the object
    Select -Expand Group |
    # And get the properties
    Where { $_.Serial -ne $null }
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but this looks like PS 3.0 syntax (`$_.Group.Serial`). You should specify that in the answer as lots of the readers here still use PS 2.0

Comment: ah, so it is. Assuming the data is already unique, I just need to add an index.

Comment: ($collection1 + $collection2) | Group-object -property Name | Where {$_.Count -eq 2 -and $_.group.Serial -ne $null} | Select -expand Group | where {$_.Serial -ne $null}  This was the solution that worked for me.  The original returned all of the objects that didn't appear in collection2.  Works very quickly as well. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, sorry I thought you were trying to get the ones NOT in the second list. Since you want the matches, you don't even need the `$_.Group.Serial` clause in the where, just `$_.Count -gt 1`

Comment: Updated to answer the OP question, and incorporate comments

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you're after, I'd start by creating a hash table from your Object1 collection:

```
$object1_hash = @{}
 Foreach ($object1 in $object1_coll)
  { $object1_hash[$object1.Name] = $object1.ResourceID }
```

Then you can find the ResourceID for any given Object2.name with:

```
$object1_hash[$Object2.Name]
```

Test bed for creating hash table:

```
$object1_coll = $(
 New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name = 'Name1';ResourceID = 001}
 New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name = 'Name2';ResourceID = 002}
 )

$object1_hash = @{}
 Foreach ($object1 in $object1_coll)
  { $object1_hash[$object1.Name] = $object1.ResourceID }

$object1_hash

Name                       Value                                                                                             
----                       -----                                                                                             
Name2                          2                                                                                                 
Name1                          1
```

Comment: I must be missing something.  When I use the code for creating the hash table, $object1_hash is empty

Comment: Added a test / demo script for creating the hash table.